# Contract owner address changing

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

I was trying to create a simple quote registry having a mapping defined as:

```
mapping (string => quoteOwner) quoteRegistry;
```

where quoteOwner structure is:

```
struct quoteOwner{
    address ownerAdd;
    bool hasOwner;
}
```

I did extend typical *owned* contract and I identified that contract owner's address went on changing as soon as I called functions like *register_quote*.

The code I was using initially was:

```
quoteOwner new_owner;
new_owner.ownerAdd=msg.sender;
new_owner.hasOwner=true;
quoteRegistry[_quote]=new_owner;
```

and I figured out,the line `new_owner.ownerAdd=msg.sender;` was causing the issue.
As soon as I changed the above to simple assignment:

```
quoteRegistry[_quote]=quoteOwner(msg.sender,true);
```

Everything is working perfectly fine! Can anyone help with what is wrong with the former method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line should have caused a couple of compiler warnings:

```
quoteOwner new_owner;
```

The implicit location for `new_owner` is `storage`. This is better written explicitly:

```
quoteOwner storage new_owner;
```

The other warning is that this is an *uninitialized storage reference*. If you've used languages like C, this is roughly the equivalent of an uninitialized pointer. It points to slot 0 in storage. That's where the first state variable in your smart contract resides. So changing `new_owner` will overwrite that first state variable, whatever it is.

There are two potential fixes. The first fix is to use a **memory** variable:

```
quoteOwner memory new_owner;
...
quoteOwner[_quote] = new_owner;
```

Here, you've declared the variable is residing in memory. This gives you a newly-allocated struct to work with, and then the value is copied into storage in the last line.

The second fix is to **initialize the storage reference**:

```
quoteOwner storage new_owner = quoteOwner[_quote];
new_owner.ownerAdd = msg.sender;
new_owner.hasOwner = true;
```

This points `new_owner` directly at the slot in storage you're trying to edit. There's no need to do an assignment at the end, because you were already editing the right data in storage.

The latter approach is slightly less code and slightly more gas efficient, so it's what I would recommend.